# Formulario W-9 I-9 en Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, formularios

buenas, amigos tengo una duda y no sé por donde partir, necesito realizar un formulario normal en laravel con los datos que pide los formularios W-9 y I-9 de EE. UU., y luego generar el pdf como si fuese el original que da la página oficial https://www.uscis.gov/ dicha página te deja descargar un pdf editable, pero lo que tengo que hacer es rellenar esos campos editables con un formulario hecho en laravel.

Alguien puede darme alguna sugerencia de librerías o sugerencias de como hacerlo y gracias de ante mano.